# Haar.js convert open cv xml to javascript

Tags: javascript, php, xml, opencv, haar-classifier

This project is discontinued , however the project files are still alive , simply i want to use the `haar.js` project to detect upper body in some media file (video or image ) , the current cascades in project folder doesn't contain upper body classifier , so i will have to use their tool (`haartojs.php`).

I have done the following :

1. Downloaded php for windows.
2. copied my open cv xml file to the root.
3. ran cmd command: `php haartojs.php --xml=myfile.xml`
4. seems the tool is working but i cant find the output file anywhere.

Also i checked the php file source ( im not php expert ) , did not find any line that shows any indication to write files.

any help will be appreciated.

php source file:
https://github.com/foo123/HAAR.js/blob/master/cascades/haartojs.php

Project Page:
https://github.com/foo123/HAAR.js

and this is a screenshot of the output:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the correct answer , after a bit long search , it is not related to php , it is about saving output in a file from cmd , a typical run command is as following:

```
php haartojs.php --xml=myxmlfilename.xml > myjsfilename.js
```

this will simply output the result from php operation to a js file.

Comment: Congratulations, you've now learned something about a fundamental feature of your operating system (and a very powerful one). I doubt this qualifies as a programming question nor that it belongs onto Stackoverflow. But just saying in case you're looking for some context. The more technical term is I/O-Redirection or just Redirection. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Redirection_(computing) - normally available in command-line interpreters.

Comment: @hakre i wish had that comment before hours of searching , anywa i know the fundamentals of my OS very well , it is just i havent noticed the output , thought the php would generate a new file.

Comment: Can happen. Not seeing the woods for the trees. ;) If I had seen it earlier, I would have commented earlier.

Comment: @hakre anyawy it turned out to be useless this script is a piece of crap :|

Comment: Well there probably is reason why it's discontinued? (Was on that website, it's with big letters and so...)

Comment: @hakre i know i should delete the question , but just in case someone will search for this answer in future who knows.

Comment: You should perhaps modify the title of the question to better match it then.

Comment: hi there, i am the author of the haar.js library and it is stopped as a project, since i do not maintain it anymore or add new features but the functionality works as stated. The comment is added since i just came accross the question. There are a couple of other image processing/ detection js libs out there (some are referenced in the haar.js readme)